# VBA Unexpected Character in File Name Workaround

Tags: vba, excel, path

I am using a vba shell to run an R code but I am having trouble with the file name.  The file path has a backslash followed by and underscore in it.  I am not authorized to remove the underscore.  When running the code with this path it throws an unexpected character error.  If I run the code with the files at a different path, which is not a longer term solution, the code runs seamlessly.

```
Sub RunRscript()
   Dim s As String
   Dim n As Integer
   Dim shell As Object
   Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
   Dim style As Integer: style = 1
   Dim errorCode As Integer
   Dim path As String
   path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\Rscript.exe""V:\_Our Division\R_Script.R -R & Pause "
```

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: You're missing a space after `exe""`.

Comment: That space doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It actually does, unless you're trying to execute this: `Rscript.exe"V:\_Our Division\R_Script.R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be the spacing issue in your command line. Try this:

```
path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\Rscript.exe"" ""V:\_Our Division\R_Script.R"" -R & Pause "
```

Note that I put both, the `Rscript.exe` and `R_Script.R` paths into quotes. Windows should like this better as both paths have spaces in them.